# How to position pocket hole jig based on wood thickness

Tags: woodworking

I have a very basic pocket hole jig without clamp or guide:
[image]

How far from the end of the piece of wood being drilled should this be positioned, and how can I calculate the required screw length?

Comment: Did it not come with instructions? Do you have a manufacturer and model number?

Comment: No, it's a cheap Amazon $10 sort of product. Works fine but I hadn't realised it wouldn't be intuitive!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The end of the guide is offset from the edge by the distance of the board the holes are being drilled into.  For 1/2", then set the guide back from the edge 1/2".  3/4" = 3/4" setback.  .  Use the [Kreg Screw Guide](https://www.kregtool.com/about-us/news/kreg-tool-tips-joining/choose-the-correct-screw-length.aspx) 
for the length and type of screw to use based on thickness and wood type.

[image: I]

Do some test drill on scrap wood before trying on your finished product.  The difficult part is setting the drill bit depth if your kit did not include the bit and collar.  Also clamp the two pieces together before screwing the screw in to make sure the two pieces are aligned.
The depth of drill is set by doing this.  
[image]

Comment: How _do_ you know how deep to drill (where to put the collar)? I have collars but I don't know where I'm aiming to drill _to_... into the second piece of wood? Just to the joint?

Comment: Place the guide on top of the wood and look at the board and guide from the side.  Place the drill on the side parallel to the guide.  You want the step of the drill to stop about 3/8" from the edge of the board.  I will see if I can provide a picture in my answer.